# How to solve JavaScript redirect issue on Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am fairly new to scrapy and following docs to scrape info on https://pbejobbers.com/abrasives
using my script:

```
import scrapy


class CrwSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Otim"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://pbejobbers.com/abrasives'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        pattern = r'document\.location\.href=\"(:?.*)=1\";'
        url = response.css('script::text').re_first(pattern)
        print (url)
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

        next_page = url+'=1'
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

When I run the crawler, instead of getting actual page, I am getting this javascript:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function toNumbers(d) {
        var e = [];
        d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
          e.push(parseInt(d, 16));
        });
        return e;
      }
      function toHex() {
        for (
          var d = [],
            d =
              1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array
                ? arguments[0]
                : arguments,
            e = "",
            f = 0;
          f < d.length;
          f++
        )
          e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
        return e.toLowerCase();
      }
      var a = toNumbers("de50860916c188904e9c359aaaf4f248"),
        b = toNumbers("a944ac1efe048739325d92e58868ffa1"),
        c = toNumbers("34d8ed644eb63ddaafeb01607ce6b6ce");
      document.cookie =
        "OCXS=" +
        toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) +
        "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
      document.location.href =
        "http://pbejobbers.com/abrasives?81e93addddb02a10cd0652f09370ae96=2";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The actual page consist of list of product cards. I noticed that `document.location.href` has a new url. So I grabbed it using regular expression and tried to feed it back to crawler as new URL to parse but then I get same result with `=2`ending URL. I cant seem to get to actual page.

How can I get the redirect URL and use it? I am really stuck.

Comment: They seem to have put a lot of effort into making the site as hard to scrape as possible. I doubt there is a solution to it that would fot into the format of a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot go to next page using Scrapy. As when you disable JavaScript from inspection tools, Next button stops working. Scrapy cannot render JavaScript. You have to use Selenium to scrape this page.